# Change column format from Seconds to Minutes

Tags: python, pandas

I have a DF with several columns with the data in seconds e.g: 600, which I want to convert to minutes with the following format 00:10:00.

I have found the following code and ran some tests it does work as expected, however, I have several columns which I want to change the format and I'm looking for the most efficient way to run the code without having to create a function for each column.

Thanks in advance.

```
def format_duration(row):
      seconds = row.Default_Misc  ## changed this
      minutes, seconds = divmod(seconds, 60)
      hours, minutes = divmod(minutes, 60)
      return '{:02d}:{:02d}:{:02d}'.format(hours, minutes, seconds)


aux['Default_Misc'] = aux.apply(format_duration, axis=1)
aux.to_csv(folder_path / 'Report.csv', index=False, encoding='UTF-8')
```

Again, currently, I'm able to apply the function to the column ['Default_Misc'], however, there are more columns that required the format change.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Time': [600,1200,1800,2000]})

pd.to_timedelta(df['Time'], 's')

0   00:10:00
1   00:20:00
2   00:30:00
3   00:33:20
```

You can make it a timedelta, and tell it that your column is seconds.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
# sample data
np.random.seed(1)
df = pd.DataFrame({'sec': np.random.randint(200,500, 5)})

# format:
df['sec'].astype('datetime64[s]').dt.strftime("%H:%M:%S")
```

output:

```
0    00:03:57
1    00:07:15
2    00:04:32
3    00:07:35
4    00:06:43
Name: sec, dtype: object
```

if you want to update your data:

```
df['sec'] = df['sec'].astype('datetime64[s]').dt.strftime("%H:%M:%S")
```

Comment: This is what I was looking for, I was able to create a function to iterate thru all the columns and change the format... thanks a lot

Comment: Actually, my solution only works for less than 24 hours. You should go for @BenPap's answer

Answer (score 0):

A longer, more cumbersome version:

```
def timeFormat(seconds, format):
    dt = str(datetime.timedelta(seconds=seconds))
    return (datetime.datetime.strptime(dt, '%H:%M:%S')).strftime(format)

fr = pd.DataFrame({'Datetimes':[600, 1200, 3600]})
fr = fr.Datetimes.apply(timeFormat, format='%H:%M:%S')
```